# Specflow V 3 Selenium BDD Error while running test

Tags: selenium, bdd, specflow

I am getting error below while running the test,

> Message: OneTimeSetUp: System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.RuntimePluginAttribute' from assembly 'TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41'.

I am Using:

- Specflow v3.1.62
- Baseclass.contrib.specflow.selenium.nunit v1.3.1
- VSTS 2017

Answer (score 0):

The last time I checked Baseclass.contrib.specflow.selenium.nunit does only support SpecFlow 1.9.

We changed a lot in the plugin infrastructure in the meantime and so it doesn't work anymore.

You have to use something else.

One option would be an example we created some time ago which uses multiple SpecFlow+Runner features to get the same functionality as Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit.

You can find it here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/tree/master/SeleniumWebTest

We also wrote an blog article about this: https://specflow.org/2018/single-test-targeting-multiple-browsers/

---

Full disclosure: I am one of the developers/maintainers of SpecFlow and SpecFlow+.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure how this answers the question. How should @DarkKnightRises fix the problem?

Comment: @GregBurghardt you are right. I added now a possible option how to get the same functionality. I was in a hurry and wanted to give DarkKnightRises a n answer that his current setup will never work.